# Zf2 setEventManager issues

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have been following a tutorial on creating Restful Applications in Zend Framework 2, all has been going well until I tried to implement this code as described in the tut :

```html
    public function setEventManager(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        $this->events = $events;
        // Register a listener at high priority
        $events->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'checkOptions'), 10);
    }
```

Im getting the following error :

> Fatal error: Declaration of Api\Controller\WebsitesController::setEventManager() must be compatible with Zend\EventManager\EventManagerAwareInterface::setEventManager(Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface $eventManager) in /var/www/html/learnzf2/public_html/module/Api/src/Api/Controller/WebsitesController.php on line 10

The tutorial is available here : https://www.zend.com/topics/ZF2REST-20130404.pdf

if anyone can shed some light on what might be causing the issue I would be most grateful.

Thanks in advance

Dave

Answer (score 2):

The interface enforces `setEventManager::$events` is a class implementing the interface `Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface`; you have however broken this as `EventManagerInterface` is just a alias to the fully qualified class name.

You can avoid this by either, using the fully qualified class name

```
public function setEventManager(\Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface $events);
```

Alternatively, keep what you have and just add a namespace alias at the top of the class.

```
<?php
    namespace Api/Controller;

    use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInteface;
```

What is also **really important** is to ensure you call the parent `setEventManager()` otherwise all of the default configuration is overloaded, [just take a look at what else is set](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php#L159).

```
public function setEventManager(EventManagerInterface $events)
{
    parent::setEventManager($events);

    $events->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'checkOptions'), 10);
}
```